# Python: Weird behavior with signs of pytz timezones

Tags: python, datetime, pytz

I'm in Argentina, my time is GMT-3 (http://wwp.greenwichmeantime.com/time-zone/south-america/argentina/)

I was playing with Pytz and noticed something weird, take a look:

```
from pytz import timezone
bsas = timezone('America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires')

gmt_plus_3 = timezone('Etc/GMT+3')
gmt_min_3 = timezone('Etc/GMT-3')

# Date and time at this momement: 2012-07-26 10:23:01

fmt = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'
datetime.now(bs).strftime(fmt)  #'2012-07-26T10:23:01' <-- GOOD!

datetime.now(gmt_min_3).strftime(fmt)  #'2012-07-26T16:25:21' <-- WRONG!

datetime.now(gmt_plus_3).strftime(fmt)  #'2012-07-26T10:23:01' <-- GOOD! WTF!
```

I'd expect:

```
GMT-3 should be 10:23:01 and gives me 16:23:01
GMT+3 should be 16:23:01 and gives me 10:23:01
```

Is this a bug? Am i doing it wrong??

Comment: Tip: use [`.isoformat()`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.isoformat) to format your datetime objects as IS 8601 strings instead of using an explicit formatter.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - unfortunately that doesn't bring much. I am having the same results.

Comment: Sorry, no, I don't know what is going on here, just commenting on your use of strftime.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not a bug, it is a feature ([Wikipedia: **Tz_database**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database#Area)):

*The special area of Etc is used for some administrative zones, particularly for "Etc/UTC" which represents Coordinated Universal Time. In order to conform with the POSIX style, those zone names beginning with "Etc/GMT" **have their sign reversed** from what most people expect. In this style, zones west of GMT have a positive sign and those east have a negative sign in their name (e.g "Etc/GMT-14" is 14 hours ahead/east of GMT.)*