# Handling per-object timezone settings in Django

Tags: django, timezone

I have a Django application in which a user can create an Activity, and then for an Activity create a number of Log entries. An Activity has a created datetime, and a Log entry also has a created datetime.

The Activity should be created with the timezone of the creating user at the time at which they create it. Specifically, a given user may have two Activities in separate timezones; the timezone setting is *not* per-user, but per-activity. I can derive a user's current offset from UTC in JavaScript in the browser (and I'm happy to rely on that).

What I do not know is: how do I save these times to the database, and then display them correctly on rendering?

I have USE_TZ turned on. Here in the UK, everything works: when creating an Activity, I save the created datetime as `django.utils.timezone.now()`, and I save the user's current offset (from JavaScript) as timezoneHoursOffset in the Activity. Then, when I display the Activity and its Log entries on a page, I wrap this in `{% timezone "Etc/GMT+(timezoneHoursOffset)" %} ... {% endtimezone %}`.

However, this approach doesn't work if the server's not in the UK. The time is saved in the database as UTC (I've verified this by checking in the database itself, not using the ORM), that time is then "changed" by the ORM to be eight hours behind UTC (because the server's timezone is UTC-8) (and that gives the correct time!) and then the `{% timezone %}` tag subtracts *another* eight hours off the time, meaning that the displayed time is eight hours behind what it should be.

I'm not sure whether I should be saving the times differently; changing them on output; using the timezone template tag; or something else. This stuff is very confusing. How would you advise that I handle this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ref [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11670425/python-weird-behavior-with-pytz-timezones/11670743#11670743), "Etc/GMT" timezones have their sign reversed. For example, I'm in +0800, it should be `'Etc/GMT-8'` instead of `'Etc/GMT+8'` (and I suspect that your UTC-8 actually should be `"Etc/GMT+8"` ):

```
>>> from django.template import Template, Context
>>> from django.utils.timezone import now
>>> print(Template("""{% load tz %}
localtime: {{ t }}
Etc/GMT-8: {{ t|timezone:"Etc/GMT-8" }}
Etc/GMT+8: {{ t|timezone:"Etc/GMT+8" }}
""").render(Context({'t':now()})))

localtime: Jan. 29, 2013, 11:48 p.m.
Etc/GMT-8: Jan. 29, 2013, 11:48 p.m.
Etc/GMT+8: Jan. 29, 2013, 7:48 a.m.
```

So, you have to reverse your `timezoneHoursOffset`...

For DB storing, according to [the doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#std:templatefilter-timezone), it's better to store data in UTC.

Also, you need to make sure your javascript generates correct hour offset because of DST. If you can, it's better to store timezone name and use it accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil import zoneinfo

from_zone = zoneinfo.gettz('UTC')
to_zone = zoneinfo.gettz('UK/UK') 

utc = created # your datetime object from the db

# Tell the datetime object that it's in UTC time zone since 
# datetime objects are 'naive' by default
utc = utc.replace(tzinfo=from_zone)

# Convert time zone
eastern_time = utc.aztimezone(to_zone)
```

Comment: That will set the timezone for the whole session. If I'm displaying more than one Activity on a page, then they might have different timezones, so they'll need to be displayed differently.

Comment: Then you must create setting for that. Allow user to save their own timezone. You can use the code above in saving timezone. I have also done this, I allow my user to select on their own.

Comment: Ah, precisely what I'm avoiding is to have timezones per-user; they are per-Activity. A given user may have two Activities in different timezones; there isn't one timezone which applies to all of a user's Activities.